# white line between sections fullpage.js

Tags: fullpage.js

I am getting a bottom white border in chrome while using fullpage.js. I have seen this issue before but have yet to have a solution that works for me. Below is the site I am having issues with:

[my website](http://davegunndesign.com)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please tell us what you have tried and share the revelant code. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't see any line :)